# How to reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic to correctly remove it?

Tags: apt, updates, dpkg

I ran into a low space on `/boot` issue and I issued the following command to try and clean it out:

```
# rm /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-{x, y, z, 70}-generic && dpkg --purge linux-image-4.4.0-{x, y, z, 70}-generic
```

Where `x`, `y` are `z` are versions I removed and don't remember their number.

But when I try to update anything and this is shown on the console:

```
# apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
Hit:1 http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://mintlinux.mirror.triple-it.nl/packages serena InRelease                        
Get:3 http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                     
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                  
Hit:6 http://mintlinux.mirror.triple-it.nl/packages serena Release                          
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/atareao/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                  
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                  
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Get:12 http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                  
Hit:14 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                       
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                       
Hit:16 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease                           
Hit:17 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_6.x xenial InRelease
Hit:18 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease
Hit:19 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Fetched 306 kB in 2s (108 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic (4.4.0-70.91) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic is not configured yet.
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-virtual:
 linux-image-extra-virtual depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.4.0.70.76); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-virtual (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-70-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image-extra-virtual
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg --configure linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic` and try again

Comment: `Setting up linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic (4.4.0-70.91) ...
Internal Error: Could not find image (/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have found, removing files before purging their package causes problems for the package manager.  You basically just have to restore the things you deleted, that the package manager is complaining about.  The restored file(s) may be of zero length, package manager doesn't care, so use the "touch" command. e.g.:

```
sudo touch /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-70-generic
```

You might have to make some directories too, but when the package manager finds the files it wants, it will successfully complete.